# How to find $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{a n + b n^2}$?

Tags: summation

I am trying to compute some quantity like a partition function for a harmonic oscillator type system and at the end of the computation I am coming across a sum that looks like,

\begin{align}
S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{an +bn^2}
\end{align}

with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. How do I find the sum? Any help regarding the same is highly appreciated.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153027/rewriting-infinite-sum-as-theta-function?noredirect=1 . Unfortunately there was no answer there.

Comment: Are you asking for a closed-form formula (which might not exist), a numerical approximation method, or what?

Comment: @RobertIsrael A Closed-form formula if possible would be best, otherwise, a numerical approximation method will do.